# Aggregating Results from Previous Rows

Tags: bash, python-2.7, shell, unix, scripting

I want to aggregate rows in a sorted file (size around 200MB)

I'm looking to consolidate numeric values of each row by taking the average if a 'uri' value matches the previous value

And the character values to be consolidated with their common name before a special character (? in the 3rd and 4th rows of the input)

**INPUT**

```
date, time-taken, uri
10/Jan/2018, 0.0001, /files/web/images/favicon1.png
10/Jan/2018, 0.0002, /files/web/images/favicon2.png
10/Jan/2018, 0.004, /files/web/Login?jsessionid=32wew.jsp
10/Jan/2018, 0.002, /files/web/Login?jsessionid=78trq.jsp
10/Jan/2018, 0.001, /files/web/userManagement.jsp
10/Jan/2018, 0.003, /files/web/userManagement.jsp
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
date, time-taken, uri
10/Jan/2018, 0.0001, /files/web/images/favicon1.png
10/Jan/2018, 0.0002, /files/web/images/favicon2.png    
10/Jan/2018, 0.003, /files/web/Login.jsp
10/Jan/2018, 0.002, /files/web/userManagement.jsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A list
while read -r line; do
    iter="$(cut -d, -f3- <<<"$line")"
    list["${iter%%\?*}"]+="+($(cut -d, -f2 <<<"$line"))"
done < input.txt

for line in "${!list[@]}"; do
    retn="$(bc -l <<<"(0 ${list["$line"]}) / $(tr -dc + <<<"${list["$line"]}" | wc -c)" |
            sed "s:0*$::")"
    echo "$retn $line"
done
```

Contents of `input.txt`:

```
10/Jan/2018, 0.0001, /files/web/images/favicon1.png
10/Jan/2018, 0.0002, /files/web/images/favicon2.png
10/Jan/2018, 0.004, /files/web/Login?jsessionid=32wew.jsp
10/Jan/2018, 0.002, /files/web/Login?jsessionid=78trq.jsp
10/Jan/2018, 0.001, /files/web/userManagement.jsp
10/Jan/2018, 0.003, /files/web/userManagement.jsp
```

Output:

```
.002  /files/web/userManagement.jsp
.003  /files/web/Login
.0001  /files/web/images/favicon1.png
.0002  /files/web/images/favicon2.png
```

The dates are omitted because there is not enough information on what to do with them when they don`t match in different instances of the same filename.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will redirect the output to a new file and for `jsessionid` I will append `.jsp` using `grep`